# page.$eval() not finding selector, selector works in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to use Puppeteer to get the src attribute from an embedded video in a page.

I have tried using page.$eval(), page.evaluate() and page.evaluateHandle() using document.querySelector().

```
const url = await page.$eval('.video > source:nth-child(3)', el => el.src);
```

The HTMl structure is as follows:

```
<video class="video media" id="" alt="" height="1080" width="1920" autoplay="" playsinline="" preload="auto" poster="" tabindex="-1">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="" type="video/webm">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    <meta itemprop="contentUrl" content="">
</video>
```

When I try to use `page.$eval` to find the element, I get the error "Error: failed to find element matching selector ".video > source:nth-child(3)""

I am able to use `document.querySelector('.video > source:nth-child(3)');` in the console, and it returns the html element:

```
<source src=​"https:​/​/​giant.gfycat.com/​VastGrayGazelle.mp4" type=​"video/​mp4">​
```

I am also able to search the HTML by selector and it highlights the element.

Comment: Are you sure, the button is already available when the page is loaded? If you add `await page.waitForSelector('.video > source:nth-child(3)');` before calling the function, does it work?

Comment: Try this - ```const videoUrl = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("#<your_id> source").getAttribute("src")));
console.log(videoUrl);```

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
    const node = await page.$('.video > source:nth-child(3)');
    const url = await page.evaluate(body => body.getAttribute('src'), node);
    console.log(url);
```